# how to configure ~/.emacs to run multiple frames with diferent background colors?

Tags: emacs

How to configure `~/.emacs` to run multiple frames with different background color?

Because I used to use 3 frames open directories with several files inside and I do not want to misdirected directory, I usually use 3 frames.

Comment: Can you run 3 frames with the same colour? If so, please include the code.

Comment: i want run for first time 3 frames with diferent background color

Answer (score 2):

All you should have to do is call `make-frame` with the appropriate parameter:

```
(make-frame '((background-color . "blue")))
(make-frame '((background-color . "red")))
(make-frame '((background-color . "green")))
```

but I suspect you will have to customize more parameters to make things readable (e.g. white foreground on green background is probably unreadable).

BTW, to find out what the names of the parameters are, say

```
(frame-parameters)
```